# React-table add total as first row

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm using react-table 6.9.2. I want to be able to add a row at the top (right under the header) that displays the total of each column.

Here is my function that just outputs a table with static values:

```
function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      one: 2,
      two: 10.4,
      three: 10.1,
      four: 54,
      five: 5,
      six: 5,
      seven: 10,
      eight: 10,
      nine: 10
    },
    {
      one: 1,
      two: 10.4,
      three: 10.1,
      four: 54,
      five: 5,
      six: 5,
      seven: 10,
      eight: 10,
      nine: 10
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactTable
        data={data}
        showPagination={false}
        columns={[
          {
            Header: "Sales Overview",
            columns: [
              {
                Header: "one",
                id: "one",
                accessor: "one",
                show: true
              },
              {
                Header: "two",
                accessor: "two",
                show: true
              },
              {
                Header: "three",
                id: "three",
                accessor: "three",
                show: true
              },
              {
                Header: "four",
                id: "four",
                accessor: "four",
                show: true
              },
              {
                Header: "five",
                id: "five",
                accessor: "five",
                show: true
              },
              {
                Header: "six",
                id: "six",
                accessor: "six",
                show: true
              },
              {
                Header: "seven",
                id: "seven",
                show: true,
                accessor: "seven"
              },
              {
                Header: "eight",
                id: "eight",
                show: true,
                accessor: "eight"
              },
              {
                Header: "nine",
                id: "nine",
                accessor: "nine",
                show: true
              }
            ]
          }
        ]}
        loading={false}
        minRows={1}
        className="-striped -highlight"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is there a way I can add a total row at the top? Even if I get the total value of each column sent within data, can I order it to always display the total row at the top?

In case it's any help, I have also created a sandbox to show the table: https://codesandbox.io/s/2vz3z741op

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An easy fix would be to discard the main Header (Sales overview), and use the subheaders to hold the aggregate columns (total rows)

Comment: @jgoday Could u show me an example? I don't understand how it'd work

Comment: Ok, https://codesandbox.io/s/xp19oy14np. React-table only seems to support until 2 nested headers, so you can use the second level to mimic a total footer one. Excuse me the code indentation and style mess, but I'm on an old laptop with a faulty keyboard ...

Comment: @jgoday looks good thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just add a totals entry to the data array:

https://codesandbox.io/s/qv7vjpr69

```
const getTotals = (data, key) => {
  let total = 0;
  data.forEach(item => {
    total += item[key];
  });
  return total;
};
function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      one: "first row",
      two: 10.4,
      ...
    },
    {
      one: "second row",
      two: 10.4,
      ...
    }
  ];
  data.unshift({
    one: "totals",
    two: getTotals(data, "two"),
    three: getTotals(data, "three"),
    four: getTotals(data, "four"),
    five: getTotals(data, "five"),
    six: getTotals(data, "six"),
    seven: getTotals(data, "seven"),
    eight: getTotals(data, "eight"),
    nine: getTotals(data, "nine")
  });
```